# Render Django template from command line, without settings

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to render a Django template from command line without invoking any settings? I want to do this outside any Django apps or project, to be able to use it as a command line tool to render a template with some variables. Is there a tool that does this already? Jinja2 would be fine too.

Comment: Yes, of course, but you'll probably have to extract some of the functionality from Django's guts to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`settings.configure()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module) if you don't have any custom settings to configure.

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
from django.template import Template, Context
Template('Hello, {{ name }}!').render(Context({'name': 'world'}))
```

To load templates from disk, you have to do slightly more work.

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/path/to/template'],
    }
]
settings.configure(TEMPLATES=TEMPLATES)
django.setup()
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
template = get_template('my_template.html')
template.render(Context({'name': 'world'})
```

Note that this answer is for Django 1.8+