# Render a django template without a django app

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django.  I have the following Django template, and I would like to render it to display the username variable.  How can I do this without setting up an entire Django app structure?

```
<html>
  <body>
    hello <strong>{{username}}</strong>
    your account is activated.
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442893/render-django-template-from-command-line-without-settings), but when I run the code there, I get an error message:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: No DjangoTemplates backend is configured.
```

Comment: Use the Jinja templating engine. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#basics

Comment: @Mess, Can you be more specific?  I'm very new to this.

Comment: Are you needing to render this server-side or client-side? In either case, all you'd need is a template engine that supports "handlebars" or "moustache" syntax. There are several libraries that can handle this depending on your needs

Comment: @BrandonTaylor For the moment I am just looking to handle this inside of a script.  All I'd like to do is define a context and render the template within that context.  The actual templates I'm rendering are far more complicated than this toy example.  I'm just using this as a starting point.

Comment: When you say "script", do you mean a JavaScript function? a Python function?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor Python.  Ideally, I read in the Django template and output a rendered HTML file with all variables filled in, all for loops executed, all if statements parsed, etc.

Comment: I would use Jinja to do that. You'll have the least amount of overhead to set up the necessary context to render the template. Keep in mind that not all Django template concepts are compatible with Jinja, but it's very close.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor Can you provide some minimal code to do that?

Comment: If you follow the basic example that @Mess provided in the first comment, you'll be on your way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Error: No DjangoTemplates backend is configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834226/django-error-no-djangotemplates-backend-is-configured)

Comment: Share exactly what you’ve tried so far

Answer (score 0):

make a view for it and return the username in the context

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def view(request):
    username = get the username
    /// if you have a login/register functionality use username = 
    request.user.username
    ///
    context = {'username': username}
    return render(request, "templates/template.html", context=context)
```

don't forget to add the view to the urls